# Place a red dot on images with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am parsing a text file which contains references to local images followed by coordinates.

```
Click "{ImageFolder}/1411634917956.png" 8 29
Click "{ImageFolder}/3465738200284.png" 23 45
Click "{ImageFolder}/7848239847583.png" 38 15
```

The output is a html file displaying the images
Text above parsed to html:

```
<img src="./scripts/images/1411634917956.png">
<img src="./scripts/images/3465738200284.png">
<img src="./scripts/images/7848239847583.png">
```

I also want to parse the coordinates, which means % of image height from top and % of image width from left, to add a red dot to the image on the specified coordinates.

I have tried the following, but the :before tag doesn't seem to be dynamically updated

### DEMO

```css
div:before{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width:5px;height:5px;
    background:red;
    content:'';
}
div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img style="left:10%;top:10%;" src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/japanese-grumpy-cat-angry-koyuki-moflicious-22.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you parsing the co-ordinates?

Comment: I use a simple python script that just reads the lines from the text file and do some string manipulation. I will be looking for numbers after .png" and use them.

Answer (score -1):

position it absolute and then change `top` and `left` OR `bottom` and `right` value.

```css
.container{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.image-container{
height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

img{
  height:100%;
}

.image-container:before{
  content:"";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://static.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/japanese-grumpy-cat-angry-koyuki-moflicious-22.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The file I am parsing contains lots of rows like this:
Click "{ImageFolder}/1413224817956.png" 34 7
Click "{ImageFolder}/1238769717354.png" 8 29
Click "{ImageFolder}/5728926409374.png" 12 91
So each image have its own coordinates. When using :before the values cannot be updated in the html. Or am I doing it wrong?
<div class="container">
 <div class="image-container" style="left:10%;top:10%">
 <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.pmarinc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/which-type-of-dog-barks-the-least.jpg"/>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: you should mention that in your question as well

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity. Thank you!